# Catch the error in testthat but dont stop the loop - testing

Tags: r, unit-testing, testing, package, testthat

I have written a package recently and I would like to test few functions where the functions delivers a data.frame when the input is correct, if not it delivers the input as a file into an error folder and logs into a log.log file.

Now the question is: How can i report this movement and do a test that the functions are moving the files into the error folder in test_that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about just calling your function with the incorrect input and afterwards checking if the error files were created as you wanted?

```
test_that("Error file is created", {
  yourfunction(x)
  expect_true(file.exists("errorfile.error")
})
```

Before `yourfunction()` you also have to create your incorrect input x.

Comment: Hmm... Good idea!